# Are there cases using the Perceptron algorithm where I do NOT want to permute the data before every iteration?

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

My machine learning textbook asks this question, discussing the perceptron algorithm, and I really can't come up with a satisfied answer.

What cases are there?

Answer (score 1):

Like any iterative learning algorithm with no globally optimal solution the perceptron algorithm will converge from a starting point to a locally optimal solution.
This usually means the early data will have a larger influence than the later.

In most applications of a perceptron algorithm you try to eliminate this bias by multiple application of the training data in random order.

In some application, this bias is part of the learning problem, so the order matters and the final result is better with no randomization.

Comment: I think that there are no local minima if you are just trying to maximize the margin.  Also, the preceptron algorithm will always converge in a finite number of steps if the data is linearly seperable.